# calculate the angle between 2 vectors, clockwise and from 0 to 2*pi

Tags: matlab, geometry

I have two (2-D) vectors with a common vertex ( I had made these 2 vectors out of 3 given points ) . I want to find the angle between them, from 0 to 2*pi, and I need it clockwise and positive. I currently use this:

```
v1=[x1 y1]-[X Y];
v2=[x2 y2]-[X Y];
ang = mod(atan2(v1(1)*v2(2)-v2(1)*v1(2),v1(1)*v2(1)+v1(2)*v2(2)),2*pi);
if ang==0
    Angle=ang; 
else
    Angle=360 - (ang*180/pi);   % change Radian to Degree
end
```

Although it works correctly, I was wondering if there is any better way to find the angle, maybe not using **if/else**??!

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use the Law of cosines.... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines

Comment: Well you could do this instead of `if...else`: `Angle=(360 - (ang*180/pi))*(ang~=0)` i suppose

Comment: have you actually considered working with complex numbers? it seems very useful here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to restrict the output to the half-open interval `[0, 360)`. In that case, simply do the `mod` at the end, after your other conversions, no `if` required:

```
ang = atan2(v1(1)*v2(2)-v2(1)*v1(2),v1(1)*v2(1)+v1(2)*v2(2));
Angle = mod(-180/pi * ang, 360);
```

Answer (score 1):

The *clockwise* angle is the exact opposite from what `atan2` assumes, so you just have to negate it:

```
Angle = mod(-atan2(v1(1)*v2(2)-v1(2)*v2(1), v1*v2'), 2*pi) * 180/pi;
```

which is, in essence, identical to Bas' answer I see now :)